# Different page numbers for `frontmatter` and `mainmatter` of book in quarto pdf format

Tags: r, pdf, latex, knitr, quarto

I need to obtain separate page numbers for the `frontmatter` and  `mainmatter` sections of a book in the [quarto](/questions/tagged/quarto) [pdf](/questions/tagged/pdf) format. I have the following  `YAML` code in my `_quarto.yml` file. I'm curious about the approach to achieve this.

```
project:
  type: book

execute:
  echo: false
  warning: false
  
book:
  title: "Title"
  author: "Author"
  chapters:
    - index.qmd
    - Ch01.qmd
    - Ch02.qmd
    - references.qmd

bibliography: references.bib

format:
  pdf:
    documentclass: scrreprt
    toc: true
    toc-depth: 3
    lof: true
    lot: true
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on "separate page number"? Like romans for frontmatter and Arabic  for mainmatter? And by frontmatter do you mean pages before "chapter 01" or before "index"?

Comment: Yes. I am looking for Romans for frontmatter and Arabic for mainmatter and mainmatter starts from "Chapter 01".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `\pagenumbering{<style>}` command, where the `<style>` could be one of,

- `arabic`: use Arabic numerals (1, 2, 3, ...)
- `roman`: use lowercase roman numerals (i, ii, iii, ...)
- `Roman`: use uppercase roman numerals (I, II, III, ...)
- `alph`: use lowercase letters (a, b, c, ...)
- `Alph`: use uppercase letters (A, B, C, ...)

So to get `Roman` page-numbering up to the `Ch01`, use `\pagenumbering{Roman}` using `include-before-body` which starts `Roman` page-numbering just after the title page. And then at the top of `Ch01.qmd` use `\pagenumbering{arabic}` to reset the page-numbering in `arabic` numerals.

```
project:
  type: book

execute:
  echo: false
  warning: false
  
book:
  title: "Title"
  author: "Author"
  chapters:
    - index.qmd
    - Ch01.qmd
    - Ch02.qmd
    - references.qmd

bibliography: references.bib

format:
  pdf:
    documentclass: scrreprt
    toc: true
    toc-depth: 3
    lof: true
    lot: true
    include-before-body: 
      text: |
        \pagenumbering{Roman}
```

**Ch01.qmd**

```
\pagenumbering{arabic}

# Introduction

This is a book created from markdown and executable code.

See @knuth84 for additional discussion of literate programming.
```

Comment: Would highly appreciate it if you guide me how to include lot (list of tables) and lof (list of figures) in toc (Table of Contents). Thanks

Comment: Sure but I would really appreciate if you could create a separate question. Because I think the answer should be concise and to the point and specific to single questions. So please make a separate question : )

Comment: The new question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76353071/707145).