# List of Tables and List of Figures in Table of Contents using Quarto book in pdf format

Tags: r, pdf, latex, knitr, quarto

I would like to get List of Tables (`lot`) and List of Figures (`lof`) in Table of Contents (`toc`)  a book in the [quarto](/questions/tagged/quarto) [pdf](/questions/tagged/pdf) format. I have the following  `YAML` code in my `_quarto.yml` file. I'm curious about the approach to achieve this.

```
project:
  type: book

execute:
  echo: false
  warning: false
  
book:
  title: "Title"
  author: "Author"
  chapters:
    - index.qmd
    - Ch01.qmd
    - Ch02.qmd
    - references.qmd

bibliography: references.bib

format:
  pdf:
    documentclass: scrreprt
    toc: true
    toc-depth: 3
    lof: true
    lot: true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the latex package [`tocbibind`](https://mirror.niser.ac.in/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/tocbibind/tocbibind.pdf). From the package documentation,

> The tocbibind package enables the titles of the Table of Contents, the List of
> Figures, the List of Tables, the Bibliography and the Index all to be added to the
> Table of Contents. By default, all of these document elements, if they exist, will
> be incorporated into the Table of Contents.

So it will include the title `Table of Contents` too, which probably you do not want. To disable the inclusion of `Table of Contents`, use `nottoc` as classoption.

```
project:
  type: book

execute:
  echo: false
  warning: false
  
book:
  title: "Title"
  author: "Author"
  chapters:
    - index.qmd
    - Ch01.qmd
    - Ch02.qmd
    - references.qmd

bibliography: references.bib

format:
  pdf:
    documentclass: scrreprt
    classoption: nottoc
    toc: true
    toc-depth: 3
    lof: true
    lot: true
    include-in-header: 
      text: |
        \usepackage{tocbibind}
```

And the ToC looks like this now,

[image: ToC]

Comment: I have two follow up questions on `quarto`: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76363681/707145) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76395142/707145). Please have a quick look on them if you have time.