# Making two sided Pretty PDFs with Quarto

Tags: r, pdf, latex, knitr, quarto

(Disclaimer: I borrowed the most code from [Making Pretty PDFs with Quarto](https://nrennie.rbind.io/blog/making-pretty-pdf-quarto/).)

My code works fine with `classoption: [oneside]` but have issues with `classoption: [twoside]`.

How can I correctly render it?

```
---
book:
  title: "Title"
  author: "MYaseen208"
format:
  pdf:
    documentclass: scrreprt
    classoption: [twoside]
  # classoption: [oneside]
    toc: true
    toc-depth: 3
    lot: true
    lof: true
    include-in-header:
      - text: |
          %% load packages
          \usepackage{lipsum}
          \usepackage{geometry}
          \usepackage{xcolor}
          \usepackage{eso-pic}
          \usepackage{fancyhdr}
          \usepackage{sectsty}
          \usepackage{fontspec}
          \usepackage{titlesec}
          
          %% Set page size with a wider right margin
          \geometry{a4paper, total={170mm,257mm}, left=20mm, top=20mm, bottom=20mm, right=50mm}
          
          %% Let's define some colours
          \definecolor{light}{HTML}{E6E6FA}
          \definecolor{highlight}{HTML}{800080}
          \definecolor{dark}{HTML}{330033}
          
          %% Let's add the border on the right hand side
          \AddToShipoutPicture{% 
              \AtPageLowerLeft{% 
                  \put(\LenToUnit{\dimexpr\paperwidth-3cm},0){% 
                      \color{light}\rule{3cm}{\LenToUnit\paperheight}%
                    }%
               }%
          }
    include-before-body:
      - text: |
          %% Style the page number
          \fancypagestyle{mystyle}{
          \fancyhf{}
          \renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt}
          \fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}
          \fancyfootoffset{3.5cm}
          }
          \setlength{\footskip}{20pt}
          
          %% style the chapter/section fonts
          \chapterfont{\color{dark}\fontsize{20}{16.8}\selectfont}
          \sectionfont{\color{dark}\fontsize{18}{16.8}\selectfont}
          \subsectionfont{\color{dark}\fontsize{14}{16.8}\selectfont}
          
          %% left align title
          \makeatletter
          \renewcommand{\maketitle}{\bgroup\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
          \begin{flushleft}
            {\sffamily\huge\textbf{\MakeUppercase{\@title}}} \vspace{0.3cm} \newline
            {\Large {\@subtitle}} \newline
            \@author
          \end{flushleft}\egroup
          }
          \makeatother
---

# Introduction

\lipsum[1-50] 

# Material and Methods

\lipsum[1-20]
```

Comment: What exactly is what you trying to achieve? That the text does not cross the colored border on the right?

Comment: Thanks @Julian for your interest in my problem. For odd numbered pages, I need border on the right side and for even numbered pages, the border should be on left side for two sided book.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could test for the page to be even or odd and place your blue bar accordingly:

```
\makeatletter
\AddToShipoutPicture{%
\if@twoside
\ifodd\c@page
    \AtPageLowerLeft{%
        \put(\LenToUnit{\dimexpr\paperwidth-3cm},0){%
            \color{light}\rule{3cm}{\LenToUnit\paperheight}%
          }%
     }%
\else
    \AtPageLowerLeft{%
        \put(\LenToUnit{0cm},0){%
            \color{light}\rule{3cm}{\LenToUnit\paperheight}%
          }%
     }%
\fi
\else
    \AtPageLowerLeft{%
        \put(\LenToUnit{\dimexpr\paperwidth-3cm},0){%
            \color{light}\rule{3cm}{\LenToUnit\paperheight}%
          }%
     }%
\fi
}
\makeatother
```

Full document:

```
% Options for packages loaded elsewhere
\PassOptionsToPackage{unicode}{hyperref}
\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}
\PassOptionsToPackage{dvipsnames,svgnames,x11names}{xcolor}
%
\documentclass[
  letterpaper,
  DIV=11,
  numbers=noendperiod,
  twoside
  ]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{iftex}
\ifPDFTeX
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage{textcomp} % provide euro and other symbols
\else % if luatex or xetex
  \usepackage{unicode-math}
  \defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}
  \defaultfontfeatures[\rmfamily]{Ligatures=TeX,Scale=1}
\fi
\usepackage{lmodern}
\ifPDFTeX\else  
    % xetex/luatex font selection
\fi
% Use upquote if available, for straight quotes in verbatim environments
\IfFileExists{upquote.sty}{\usepackage{upquote}}{}
\IfFileExists{microtype.sty}{% use microtype if available
  \usepackage[]{microtype}
  \UseMicrotypeSet[protrusion]{basicmath} % disable protrusion for tt fonts
}{}
\makeatletter
\@ifundefined{KOMAClassName}{% if non-KOMA class
  \IfFileExists{parskip.sty}{%
    \usepackage{parskip}
  }{% else
    \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
    \setlength{\parskip}{6pt plus 2pt minus 1pt}}
}{% if KOMA class
  \KOMAoptions{parskip=half}}
\makeatother
\usepackage{xcolor}
\setlength{\emergencystretch}{3em} % prevent overfull lines
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-\maxdimen} % remove section numbering
% Make \paragraph and \subparagraph free-standing
\ifx\paragraph\undefined\else
  \let\oldparagraph\paragraph
  \renewcommand{\paragraph}[1]{\oldparagraph{#1}\mbox{}}
\fi
\ifx\subparagraph\undefined\else
  \let\oldsubparagraph\subparagraph
  \renewcommand{\subparagraph}[1]{\oldsubparagraph{#1}\mbox{}}
\fi


\providecommand{\tightlist}{%
  \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}}\usepackage{longtable,booktabs,array}
\usepackage{calc} % for calculating minipage widths
% Correct order of tables after \paragraph or \subparagraph
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\longtable{\par}{\if@noskipsec\mbox{}\fi\par}{}{}
\makeatother
% Allow footnotes in longtable head/foot
\IfFileExists{footnotehyper.sty}{\usepackage{footnotehyper}}{\usepackage{footnote}}
\makesavenoteenv{longtable}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\makeatletter
\def\maxwidth{\ifdim\Gin@nat@width>\linewidth\linewidth\else\Gin@nat@width\fi}
\def\maxheight{\ifdim\Gin@nat@height>\textheight\textheight\else\Gin@nat@height\fi}
\makeatother
% Scale images if necessary, so that they will not overflow the page
% margins by default, and it is still possible to overwrite the defaults
% using explicit options in \includegraphics[width, height, ...]{}
\setkeys{Gin}{width=\maxwidth,height=\maxheight,keepaspectratio}
% Set default figure placement to htbp
\makeatletter
\def\fps@figure{htbp}
\makeatother

%% load packages
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{sectsty}
%\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{titlesec}

%% Set page size with a wider right margin
\geometry{a4paper, total={170mm,257mm}, left=20mm, top=20mm, bottom=20mm, right=50mm}

%% Let's define some colours
\definecolor{light}{HTML}{E6E6FA}
\definecolor{highlight}{HTML}{800080}
\definecolor{dark}{HTML}{330033}

%% Let's add the border on the right hand side
\makeatletter
\AddToShipoutPicture{%
\if@twoside
\ifodd\c@page
    \AtPageLowerLeft{%
        \put(\LenToUnit{\dimexpr\paperwidth-3cm},0){%
            \color{light}\rule{3cm}{\LenToUnit\paperheight}%
          }%
     }%
\else
    \AtPageLowerLeft{%
        \put(\LenToUnit{0cm},0){%
            \color{light}\rule{3cm}{\LenToUnit\paperheight}%
          }%
     }%
\fi
\else
    \AtPageLowerLeft{%
        \put(\LenToUnit{\dimexpr\paperwidth-3cm},0){%
            \color{light}\rule{3cm}{\LenToUnit\paperheight}%
          }%
     }%
\fi
}
\makeatother
\KOMAoption{captions}{tableheading}
\makeatletter
\makeatother
\makeatletter
\makeatother
\makeatletter
\@ifpackageloaded{caption}{}{\usepackage{caption}}
\AtBeginDocument{%
\ifdefined\contentsname
  \renewcommand*\contentsname{Table of contents}
\else
  \newcommand\contentsname{Table of contents}
\fi
\ifdefined\listfigurename
  \renewcommand*\listfigurename{List of Figures}
\else
  \newcommand\listfigurename{List of Figures}
\fi
\ifdefined\listtablename
  \renewcommand*\listtablename{List of Tables}
\else
  \newcommand\listtablename{List of Tables}
\fi
\ifdefined\figurename
  \renewcommand*\figurename{Figure}
\else
  \newcommand\figurename{Figure}
\fi
\ifdefined\tablename
  \renewcommand*\tablename{Table}
\else
  \newcommand\tablename{Table}
\fi
}
\@ifpackageloaded{float}{}{\usepackage{float}}
\floatstyle{ruled}
\@ifundefined{c@chapter}{\newfloat{codelisting}{h}{lop}}{\newfloat{codelisting}{h}{lop}[chapter]}
\floatname{codelisting}{Listing}
\newcommand*\listoflistings{\listof{codelisting}{List of Listings}}
\makeatother
\makeatletter
\@ifpackageloaded{caption}{}{\usepackage{caption}}
\@ifpackageloaded{subcaption}{}{\usepackage{subcaption}}
\makeatother
\makeatletter
\@ifpackageloaded{tcolorbox}{}{\usepackage[skins,breakable]{tcolorbox}}
\makeatother
\makeatletter
\@ifundefined{shadecolor}{\definecolor{shadecolor}{rgb}{.97, .97, .97}}
\makeatother
\makeatletter
\makeatother
\makeatletter
\makeatother
\ifLuaTeX
  \usepackage{selnolig}  % disable illegal ligatures
\fi
\IfFileExists{bookmark.sty}{\usepackage{bookmark}}{\usepackage{hyperref}}
\IfFileExists{xurl.sty}{\usepackage{xurl}}{} % add URL line breaks if available
\urlstyle{same} % disable monospaced font for URLs
\hypersetup{
  colorlinks=true,
  linkcolor={blue},
  filecolor={Maroon},
  citecolor={Blue},
  urlcolor={Blue},
  pdfcreator={LaTeX via pandoc}}

\author{}
\date{}

\begin{document}
%% Style the page number
\fancypagestyle{mystyle}{
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt}
\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}
\fancyfootoffset{3.5cm}
}
\setlength{\footskip}{20pt}

%% style the chapter/section fonts
\chapterfont{\color{dark}\fontsize{20}{16.8}\selectfont}
\sectionfont{\color{dark}\fontsize{18}{16.8}\selectfont}
\subsectionfont{\color{dark}\fontsize{14}{16.8}\selectfont}

%% left align title
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\maketitle}{\bgroup\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\begin{flushleft}
  {\sffamily\huge\textbf{\MakeUppercase{\@title}}} \vspace{0.3cm} \newline
  {\Large {\@subtitle}} \newline
  \@author
\end{flushleft}\egroup
}
\makeatother

\ifdefined\Shaded\renewenvironment{Shaded}{\begin{tcolorbox}[boxrule=0pt, sharp corners, interior hidden, borderline west={3pt}{0pt}{shadecolor}, frame hidden, enhanced, breakable]}{\end{tcolorbox}}\fi

\renewcommand*\contentsname{Table of contents}
{
\hypersetup{linkcolor=}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\tableofcontents
}
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\hypertarget{introduction}{%
\chapter{Introduction}\label{introduction}}

\lipsum[1-50]

\hypertarget{material-and-methods}{%
\chapter{Material and Methods}\label{material-and-methods}}

\lipsum[1-20]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score -2):

replace classoption: [twoside]" with:

`classoption:`

```
 - twoside
```

Comment: How will this help if the sidebar is hard coded to be on the right side? If you check the intermediate .tex file, you will see that `[twoside]` is correctly parsed.