# Including the title page and back page in a quarto book in PDF format

Tags: r, pdf, latex, title, quarto

I'm interested in including the title page (have a title page as a `.png` image) and back page (have a back page as a `.png` image) in a quarto book that will be rendered as a PDF file. I tried the following code, however, I did not get the desired output. I would like to know the steps or methods to accomplish this.

```
---
book:
  title: "Title"
  author: "MYaseen208"
format:
  pdf:
    documentclass: scrreprt
    toc: true
    toc-depth: 3
    include-in-header:
      - text: |
          \usepackage{lipsum}
          \usepackage{geometry}
          \geometry{a4paper, total={170mm,257mm}, left=20mm, top=20mm, bottom=20mm, right=50mm}
---

# Introduction

\lipsum[1-50] 

# Material and Methods

\lipsum[1-20]
```

**Edited**

For example, if I want to include the following image as title and back page of the book.

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far? I cannot see where you try to add the `png` files..

Comment: Your code does not include any images. Can you elaborate on what you have tried so far and what kind of image you are trying to include and what is your desired output :) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add your images via the `\AtBeginDocument` and `\AtEndDocument` hooks:

```
---
book:
  title: "Title"
  author: "MYaseen208"
format:
  pdf:
    documentclass: scrreprt
    toc: true
    toc-depth: 3
    include-in-header:
      - text: |
          \usepackage{lipsum}
          \usepackage{tikz}
          \AtBeginDocument{\thispagestyle{empty}\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
          \node at (current page.center) {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight,keepaspectratio]{example-image-duck}};
          \end{tikzpicture}\clearpage}
          \AtEndDocument{\clearpage\thispagestyle{empty}\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
          \node at (current page.center) {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight,keepaspectratio]{example-image-duck}};
          \end{tikzpicture}}
---

# Introduction

\lipsum[1-50] 

# Material and Methods

\lipsum[1-20]
```

Some other comments:

- you shouldn't use the geometry package with a koma class. Koma classes have their own mechanism to change the page layout
- If you really must use the `geometry` package, at least don't ignore the warnings and don't overspecify your geometry.
- png might not be the best option for such a graphic. It does not zoom well and will get pixelated and for such a simple image it will unnecessarily blow up the file size. It would be better to include as a vector graphic.
- If you'd had your image as a full page pdf, you could use the `pdfpages` package to include it.